# Interesting determinant problem

Tags: determinant

how to go about computing following determinant? I tried using Gaussian elimination on some special cases and figured there might be some pattern, maybe a recurrence relation involved, but I just can't see it.

$\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
  2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n & 1 \\
  3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & 1 & 2 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  n & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 
 \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Here's a guess:  multiply the ith row by n!/i.  It'll make every entry in the first column identical.

Comment: This is a circulant matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix for which there is an explicit determinant formula. This may however be somehow  difficult to calculate.

Comment: @LordSoth Yes, it is easy to see what the eigenvalues are. But how to derive an explicit formula for their product?