# Solve $n$th order determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Solve $n$th order determinant:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 &n\\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1& n& 1\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & n &1 &2\\
    \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots& \vdots&\vdots\\
    n-2 &n-1&n &\cdots &n-5 &n-4 &n-3\\
    n-1 &n&1 &\cdots &n-4 &n-3 &n-2\\
    n &1&2 &\cdots &n-3 &n-2 &n-1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I tried adding $2$nd to $n$th row to the $1$st row, then the first row is:
$$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{n(n+1)}{2} &\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \cdots \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
then I took out $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ from the first row to get 
$$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & \cdots& 1\\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
and then tried to work with that but I don't think this is the correct approach because anything I tried doesn't look nice.

Comment: May be this will help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365774/how-to-solve-this-determinant-a-ij-i-j1?rq=1

Comment: @Coniferous Same remark : it is not the same determinant.

Comment: @JeanMarie The determinant is the same, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712367/interesting-determinant-problem), and the associated duplicate.

Comment: @Dietric Burde No, I insist : it is not the same. Rule $c_{i,j}=|i-j|+1$ give all super and infra diagonal with identical entries which is not the case here.

Comment: You are right, but up to permutation, i.e., up to sign, the determinant is the same, and we can regard the two problems as equivalent, I would say. This is also the reason why the $5$ people marked it as a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712367/interesting-determinant-problem).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I have fully understood what you meant (see my answer)

Comment: @JeanMarie Very nice (plus one:))

Comment: I noticed an error sign. I tracked it, and noticed, doing that, that a simplification could be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), where one can show the following formula for its determinant:

[Determinant of circulant matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770117/determinant-of-circulant-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \cdots & a_1\\
a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & \cdots & a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_n & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we have
$$
\det (A) = (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\omega_j^k\right),
$$
where $\omega_j=e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}$.
In our case it is
$$
(-1)^{n - 1}n^{n - 2}(n^2 + n)/2,
$$
see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C18%2C160%2C1875%2C27216&language=german&go=Suche), and

[Interesting determinant problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712367/interesting-determinant-problem)

Comment: A remark explaining the form of this determinant : diagonalizing a circulant matrix $A$ under the form $A=PCP^{-1}$, the diagonal elements of (diagonal) matrix $C$ are the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) of the first line $(1,2,...n)$.

Comment: The OP's determinant is an integer. Which integer? It is not clear from the formula.

Comment: @lhf Thank you. I will try to find this on MSE, too. Ah, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712367/interesting-determinant-problem) it is.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote by  $A$ the matrix corresponding to the determinant we have to compute.

Our objective is to show that :

> $$\tag{*}\det(A)=(-1)^{n-1}n^{n-2}\dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}$$

As $C:=A^T$ is circulant, we can use the following result : (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), (http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/cir-not5.pdf):

> A $n \times n$ circulant matrix $C$ is diagonalizable under the form
>
> $$C=F_n^{−1}DF_n$$
>
> where $F_n$ is the $n$-th order matrix of DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) with general term $\omega^{k\ell}$ where $\omega:=e^{-\tfrac{2 i \pi}{n}}.$
>
> Moreover if we denote by $\lambda_k$ the entries $D_{kk}$ of diagonal matrix $D$, with $V=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_n)^T$, $V$ is the DFT of the first column $(1,2,...n)^T$ of $C$ , i.e,

$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\omega^{0 \times 0}&&\cdots&&\omega^{(n-1)0}\\ &&&& \\ &&\omega^{k \ell}&&\\ &&&&\\ \omega^{0(n-1)}&&\cdots&&\omega^{(n-1)(n-1)}\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{DFT matrix} \ \ F_n}\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ n\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus:

$$\tag{1}\det(C)=\det(D)=\prod_{k=1}^n \lambda_k=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} p(\omega^k),$$

where polynomial $p$ is defined by

$$p(x):=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...+nx^{n-1}=q'(x)$$

$$\text{with} \ \ q(x):=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

As an immediate consequence :

$$\tag{2}\text{if} \ x \neq 1, \ p(x)=q(x)'=\dfrac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

In (1), let us treat separately the case $k=0$:

$$p(\omega^0)=p(1)=1+2+3+\cdots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Concerning the general case, using (2):

$$\tag{3}\text{for} \ k=1,2,... (n-1): \ \ 
p(\omega^k)= \dfrac{n(\omega^k-1)}{(\omega^k-1)^2}=n\dfrac{1}{\omega^k-1}$$

(because any $n$th root of unity at power $n$ is equal to $1$.)

As a consequence

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} p(\omega^k)=n^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\omega^k-1}$$

In view of objective (*), it remains to prove that

$$\tag{4}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\omega^k-1)=(-1)^{n-1}n.$$

This will be done by considering $r$ defined by

$$\tag{5}r(x):=1-x^n=(1-x)s(x) \ \text{with} \ \ s(x):=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}$$

But the roots of $s$ are the $\omega^k$ for $k=1\cdots (n-1)$ ; thus, the factorized form of $s$ is:

$$\tag{6}s(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x-\omega^k)$$

Setting $x=1$ in (6) and (5) resp. gives  (4).

**Remark:** This proof is different from the direct proofs using lines and columns manipulations. Its interest lies in the facts that

- it is based on mathematics (circulant matrices, Fourier Transform, $n$th roots of unity) that are beyond "tricks of the trade".
- it explains in particular why we have factors $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $n^{n-2}$ in the result.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%5B%5B1,2,3,4,5,6%5D,%5B2,3,4,5,6,1%5D,%5B3,4,5,6,1,2%5D,%5B4,5,6,1,2,3%5D,%5B5,6,1,2,3,4%5D,%5B6,1,2,3,4,5%5D%5D), we get this sequence
$$
1, -3, -18, 160, 1875, -27216, -470596, \dots
$$
[oeis/A052182](https://oeis.org/A052182) tells us that the determinant is $(-1)^{n-1}n^{n-2}\dfrac{(n^2 + n)}{2}$, except for the sign.

Comment: This formula is also given in the duplicate to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712367/interesting-determinant-problem). The answer by Librecoin has the same formula.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, it's not exactly the same matrix. Hence the difference in sign.

Comment: Therefore we have the other link, having exactly the same matrix (the determinants are equal up to sign, as you have noted).